# XCode "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" after linking C library in C++ program

Tags: c++, c, xcode, libav

I'm trying to link to libav (which I compiled on the same system (Mac 10.8)), with a C++11 program (here stripped down to minimum size reproducing the error):

```
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    av_register_all();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the link error, notice on the right in the second last line in the command where I've included "-lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil" which reside as lib*.a files in /usr/local/lib.

[image]

There are no issues when I rename the source file program to *.c, such that XCode compiles it as a C program, but I would like to use C++11.

Comment: You might want to wrap the `#include` in an `extern "C" { }` block?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Please add your comment as an answer, it's been helpful for me today but I almost missed your answer.